# What steps are required to install eclipse on Windows8 (exitcode 13)?

Tags: java, eclipse

For one hour I am trying to get eclipse to run on a Windows 8 system. I also needed to install java jre, which seem to have been installed fine:

```
C:\Users\Alexander>java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

As far as I found in forums one has to set the path to jre manually in the eclipse.ini (in some order) which I have done:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

However this gave the following error:
[image]

Did I configure something wrong? Do I need to install something else? Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Looks like you are using a 32 bit JRE with 64 bit Eclipse. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: The 64bit jre version seems to get installed under Windows\System32. This seems strange, but still ok?

Comment: The one actually being used is the one after the -vm switch in that dialog.